# CodeIgniter Calling methods within the same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is kinda a noob question.  I have a controller that update record from a database, and then display the main page.  In the update method,

```
function update() {
  $row = $this->db->update($tablename, $data);
  if($row == 1) {
    $this->index();
  }
}
```

In this case, the view goes back to the index page, but the url is still localhost/controller/update.  Should I use redirect instead?

```
function update() {
  $row = $this->db->update($tablename, $data);
  if($row == 1) {
    redirect(controller/index);
  }
}
```

Which method is the correct way of redirecting pages?  Thank you.

Comment: well, the function name tells everything: "redirect" is the best method to...redirect ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `redirect` method.  That way they can't accidently reload the page, and re-edit the row (I guess they could hit back...).

P.S. You need quotes around `controller/index`.

```
redirect('controller/index');
```

Comment: If I want to pass message, such as 'row has been successfully updated', I pass it using uri segment?

Comment: @Eric: That's one way.  Personally, I like [`flashdata`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).  Before redirecting: `$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Row Updated');`.  Then on the new page `$this->session->flashdata('message');`.